# Getting JavaScript file from Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, variables, google-sheets

In my google sheet I entered below formulas in B1 and B2

```
B1 = "name = " & "'" & A1 & "' ;"
```

```
B2 = "city = " & "'" & A2 & "' ;"
```

Then these Cells become valid JS statements
`name = 'Prabhu Paul' ;` and `city = 'India' ;`

Then I published the Sheet in **.csv** format, below is the URL.

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSQIORejF59NZEyEigMfHFpNcs-XCjKyUbTSrcWJcR0Mn3DO6oSHWeGfm3XvnqQBj1ipMI00I-r5qH7/pub?gid=0&single=true&range=b1:b2&output=csv
```

And now I used this URL as the source file for my Script.

The script added to **site header** by putting below code in my **wordpress functions.php file**

```
function ti_custom_javascript() {
    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSQIORejF59NZEyEigMfHFpNcs-XCjKyUbTSrcWJcR0Mn3DO6oSHWeGfm3XvnqQBj1ipMI00I-r5qH7/pub?gid=0&single=true&range=b1:b2&output=csv"></script>
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_head', 'ti_custom_javascript');
```

Then I tried to retrieve those variables by below way in my **webpage [JS by Sheets](https://sgquizdaily.com/jsbysheets)**

Below is the **Custom HTML Block** Code in my Page

```
<p>Hi, This is <span id="name"></span>, and I'm from <span id="city"></span> </p>

<script>
  document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = name ;
  document.getElementById("city").innerHTML = city ;
</script>
```

Here in code I tried to get the variables named **name** and **city**
The value of the **name** variable is **Prabhu Paul**
The value of the **city** variable is **India**

Actually my Paragraph element's innerHTML should like below

**Hi, This is Prabhu Paul, and I'm from India**

But it's not returning the values, how to fix this ..?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Content-Type-Options csv is blocked from being executed as javascript

Comment: In this case, how about using Web Apps as a wrapper? The sample script is `const doGet = _ => ContentService.createTextOutput(UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-###/pub?gid=0&single=true&range=b1&output=csv").getContentText()).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);`. By this, I thought that the Web Apps URL can be used as `src` of script tag.

Comment: sorry @Tanaike I did not understand what you said, are you asking me to create a google app script web app or  ..? Can you post sample script for me ?

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I posted a simple sample flow using a simple sample script. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: ok, proceeding with your solution. I will let you know ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, as a workaround, how about using Web Apps as a wrapper? The sample script is as follows.

### Usage:

#### 1. Create Google Apps Script project.

Please create a Google Apps Script project. When you access https://script.google.com/ and create a new project, you can create a Google Apps Script project of a standalone type. Please set the title of the Google Apps Script project.

#### 2. Sample script.

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of the created Google Apps Script project.

```js
const doGet = _ => ContentService.createTextOutput(UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSQIORejF59NZEyEigMfHFpNcs-XCjKyUbTSrcWJcR0Mn3DO6oSHWeGfm3XvnqQBj1ipMI00I-r5qH7/pub?gid=0&single=true&range=b1:b2&output=csv").getContentText()).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);
```

In this case, your URL is used.

#### 3. Deploy Web Apps.

The detailed information can be seen in [the official document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploy_a_script_as_a_web_app).

Please set this using the new IDE of the script editor.

1. On the script editor, at the top right of the script editor, please click "click Deploy" -> "New deployment".
2. Please click "Select type" -> "Web App".
3. Please input the information about the Web App in the fields under "Deployment configuration".
4. Please select **"Me"** for **"Execute as"**.
5. Please select **"Anyone"** for **"Who has access"**.
6. Please click "Deploy" button.
7. Copy the URL of the Web App. It's like `https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec`. This URL is used for your HTML.

#### 4. Testing.

Here, your Custom Javascript function in functions.php file was modified. Please set your Web Apps URL as follows.

```
function ti_custom_javascript() {
    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec"></script>
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_head', 'ti_custom_javascript');
```

And here, your HTML sample (not modified).

```html
<p>Hi, This is <span id="name"></span>, and I'm from <span id="city"></span> </p>
 
<script>
  document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = name ;
  document.getElementById("city").innerHTML = city ;
</script>
```

### Note:

- **When you modified the Google Apps Script of Web Apps, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.**
- You can see the detail of this in my report "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".
- In this answer, your Spreadsheet is used. Of course, you can directly set the script in Web Apps.

### References:

- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script (Author: me)](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)

Comment: Yes @Tanaike it's working very Well . I have successfully returned 2 variables. Name and city. Thank You so much

Comment: It's my [web app URL](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxebia3fgaEUX3xy4Nmxll7UzV6DgN9H3p1cigDWPgHo19IEGdOQil_9ZAleTPFRIKEHQ/exec). But I didn't understand why it's being changed on every Refresh.

Comment: @Prabhu Paul Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About `But I didn't understand why it's being changed on every Refresh.`, is this my post useful? https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43

Comment: I don't have much knowledge in coding brother. anyway my issue was solved. Thanks Again

Comment: Hello @Tanaike I'm getting extra Apostrophes in web app output lines. Can you help me in [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74288145/extra-apostrophes-coming-in-google-sheets-apps-script-web-app)

Comment: @Prabhu Paul From your comment, I answered your new question. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Hi @tanaike have you approved my edit to your above answer ?

Comment: @Prabhu Paul I cannot understand `have you approved my edit to your above answer ?`. I apologize for this.

Comment: @Prabhu Paul Oh! Now, I understood that you had requested the edit request. I couldn't notice it. I apologize for this. Now, it's done.