# Extra double quotes in csv coming in Google Sheets Apps Script Web App

Tags: javascript, csv, google-apps-script, google-sheets, double-quotes

In my google sheet I have some data in it. Later I published my sheet as **.csv** format.

Pls find **[my sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1R5Wgq4okSWz0d159X5kPvOk8W1T_6eZ2kwoq5kdjO0w/edit?usp=sharing)**, below are the **Cell Values**

```
C1 = tdsyltt = 'ఈరోజు ( బుధవారం )  క్విజ్ సిలబస్' ;

C2 = tdsyl = 'హబక్కూకు 1 & యాకోబు 2, 3' ;

C4 = document.getElementById("tdsyltt).innerHTML = tdsyltt ;

C5 = document.getElementById("tdsyl").innerHTML = tdsyl ;
```

And using my **published URL** I have developed a **web app**

**code.gs**

```
const doGet = _ => ContentService.createTextOutput(UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vReY-tDEwKYjTiSjsfAN42qjFUwMv_OD3_64bFdGrgL-2p3otc13elLcCq3pkb5xqhTA-bW3QXobpqh/pub?gid=1861615717&single=true&range=c1:c5&output=csv").getContentText()).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);
```

In the web app output 1st line is ok,

but for 2nd, 3rd and 4th line there are **Extra 2 Apostrophes** coming at the starting and ending of the lines.

Here is **[My Web App](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbw5ae5_ZLNRiDsgyZlbV5WLEdsHfodP7uhjUUCKHOp4nm1thJVC63sBvP5RhibWWFuXxA/exec)**

[image]

How to fix this ..?

Comment: Do NOT share [spreadsheets](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455)/[images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) as the only source of data, to avoid closure of the question. Make sure to add input and expected output as **plain text table** to the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easier to copy/paste as well**. Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Comment: What if you use single quote in the content of your cell ? same result ? Having double quotes arround string in CSV is valid. Why don't you use Apps Script to retrieve the content of the sheets and format it as expected instead making a url fetch call ?

Comment: Hi @ValLeNain I'm preparing my script here in sheets by app script. Because variables are in g-sheet. and then I'm using this web app URL as my script source file for my website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a way to solve this by changing the spreadsheet Publishing Format from `csv` to `tsv` then it will work.

**Code.gs**

```
const doGet = _ => ContentService.createTextOutput(UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vReY-tDEwKYjTiSjsfAN42qjFUwMv_OD3_64bFdGrgL-2p3otc13elLcCq3pkb5xqhTA-bW3QXobpqh/pub?gid=1861615717&single=true&range=c1:c5&output=tsv").getContentText()).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Modification points:

- In this case, how about directly retrieving the values from Spreadsheet using Spreadsheet service instead of `UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vReY-tDEwKYjTiSjsfAN42qjFUwMv_OD3_64bFdGrgL-2p3otc13elLcCq3pkb5xqhTA-bW3QXobpqh/pub?gid=1861615717&single=true&range=c1:c5&output=csv").getContentText()`? I thought that the reason of your current issue might be due to exporting the Spreadsheet as CSV data. When the Spreadsheet service is used, the values can be retrieved.

  - In your previous question, I said "In this answer, your Spreadsheet is used. Of course, you can directly set the script in Web Apps.". [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74276073) In your this question, I thought that this can be used.
- In your sample Spreadsheet, `document.getElementById("tdsyltt).innerHTML = tdsyltt ;` is required to be `document.getElementById("tdsyltt").innerHTML = tdsyltt ;`. Please be careful about this.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
const doGet = _ => {
  const spreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set your Spreadsheet ID.
  
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("SYLLABUSC");
  const html = sheet.getRange("C1:C6").getDisplayValues().filter(([c]) => c).join("\n");
  
  // console.log(html); // When you directly run this function with the script editor, you can see the created value in the log.
  
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(html).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);
}
```

- From your Spreadsheet, in this sample script, I used "C1:C6" of "SYLLABUSC" sheet. So, please modify this for your actual situation.

#### Note:

- **When you modified the Google Apps Script of Web Apps, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.**
- You can see the detail of this in my report "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

Comment: and in another way I tried. It's also working. Just by changing the publishing format from ```CSV``` to ```TSV```

Comment: @Prabhu Paul Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I thought that in this case, I apologize that I didn't add the sample script of this method in your previous question as one more sample script. I think that when the process cost is considered, the method using the Spreadsheet service might be lower. But, I have never measured this. I apologize for this.

Comment: Hi @tanaike which method is best when comparing these two. (1. ```Spreadsheet Service``` or 2. publishing as ```tsv```) ?

Comment: @Prabhu Paul About your additional question of `which method is best when comparing these two. (1. Spreadsheet Service or 2. publishing as tsv) ?`, as a simple test, it seems that the process cost using the Spreadsheet service is lower a little than that using UrlFetchApp.

Comment: so you recommend to use ```Spreadsheet Service``` method. Right ..?

Comment: @Prabhu Paul About `so you recommend to use Spreadsheet Service method. Right ..?`, if you want to consider the process cost, it's yes.

Comment: @Prabhu Paul About your new question, now, I noticed that your new question has already been resolved. I'm glad for it.